# CORS configuration for specific domains and allowing access from any origin in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

Body:
I'm trying to configure Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) in a Spring Boot application so that requests from specific domains are allowed, but also requests from any other origin can access a particular endpoint.

However, I can't seem to get the configuration right and requests from other origins are blocked. Here's my current configuration:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("https://example.com", "https://example2.com")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*")
            .exposedHeaders("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Language", "Content-Type", "Expires", "Last-Modified", "Pragma")
            .allowCredentials(true)
            .maxAge(3600);
}
```

This configuration works fine for requests coming from the allowed origins, but requests from any other origin are blocked. However, if I use the @CrossOrigin(origins = "*") notation in a controller method to allow any domain over that method it doesn't work.

Is there a way to configure CORS in Spring Boot so that requests from specific domains are allowed, but any other origin can access the endpoint?

```
@GetMapping("/data")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Some data");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: _I need to restrict access to specific domains._ What's preventing you from listing the Web origins in question as arguments of the `allowedOrigins` method?

Comment: because I need a specific method to be called from any domain, and I don't know the possible domains that use that method

Comment: I don't understand. You should explain that better in your question.